# Faster to append or create html elements before? -- JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am trying to make my application faster. I want some elements to appear only when an ajax request has succeeded. Is it faster to create the elements with append when the request has succeeded, or is it faster to create the html element in the actual html and simply insert the content in the element with .html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html/4): plain old `innerHTML` beats `.html()` (and `.html()` beats `.append()`).

However according to this [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml/18): `DOM` beats `innerHTML`.

So, might want to look into [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/documentFragment), specified in DOM1 and even supported in IE6 (so there is no reason not to use it).

Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page 'reflow' (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.

John Resig did a nice write-up about it [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) and concludes:

> A method that is largely ignored in modern web development can provide
>   some serious (2-3x) performance improvements to your DOM manipulation.

You just might want to combine some of those techniques *per case* you want to optimize.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have not checked, but since Resig wrote about it in 2008, I assume jquery uses documentFragment, so to me this does not really answers the question, although interesting and useful point.

Comment: I might be interpreting your question wrong. If you are asking if it saves time to create some wrapper-elements before/while loading ajax-data, then yes, that should be faster.     You can use documentFragment to (without overhead of a library, since it was speed you where asking about). Updated my answer to include some relevant JSPerf tests.